# Build a custom share panel of buttons

Tags: iphone, button, share, slide, customization

I am trying to build a custom share panel with buttons.

- This is how it appears before being clicked.

[image: screenshot]

- This is how it appears after.

  [image: screenshot]

I know that may be complicated, but I need the steps to accomplish this.

The images show the mock-ups of the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

- Create the user interface.

  [image: screenshot]
- Link the user interface with IBoutlets and IBActions.
- Animate the UIView item with buttons.

  ```
  -(IBAction) openPanelBtnPressed:(id)sender{
  CGPoint wpos = self.panel.frame.origin ;
  if(wpos.x == 0 && wpos.y ==133){
      [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
      [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
      self.panel.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,330, 76, 368);
      self.panel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;  
      [UIView commitAnimations];
  UIImage * imgOpenPanelBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"];
  [self.btnOpenPanel setImage:imgOpenPanelBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   }else {
          [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
          [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
          self.panel.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 133.0, 76, 368);
           self.panel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;  
          [UIView commitAnimations];
          UIImage * imgOpenPanelBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"];
          [self.btnOpenPanel setImage:imgOpenPanelBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   }
   }
  ```
- The result is this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zoZKjbZAps.
- You can find the explanation in Arabic on [my blog](http://mrxprt.com/blog/?p=651).
- You can [download the project](http://www.mrxprt.com/uploads/FlyingSharePanel.zip).

Answer (score 1):

You just think complicated. It is not complicated; all you need is a view on the main window with this arrow custom button, when click it just move it from bottom to top.

Comment: thanks @iTarek , really it was simple , it's in the next answer