# build Custom Share panel of buttons , android

Tags: android, animation, sliding

I am trying to build a sliding panel from top to down and vice versa.

I found the solution to build in for iphone here: [Build a custom share panel of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475447/build-custom-share-panel-of-buttons-iphone/7475706#7475706).

How can I build this panel for Android? All I need is the steps.

On [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zoZKjbZAps), you can see the panel I built for iPhone.